# In construction of an inner product that maps from a vector space to a dual, what makes the map considered to be natural?

Tags: vector-spaces, vectors, dual-spaces, dual-maps

My question is in reference to the derivation below from the physics site. It shows how the metric tensor raises and lowers indices. I cut it off halfway through because I didn't think the full derivation was relevant to the question, but [here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/333736/why-do-we-select-the-metric-tensor-for-raising-and-lowering-indices) it is, just in case. I don't believe my question is a duplicate.

[image]

My question is, why is the map $\tau$ considered to be "natural"? Does the fact that the vector space has an inner product necessitate that the dual has one? (maybe so that there's an isomorphism?)

Edit: I'm asking if the fact that the vector space has an inner product induces the need for its dual to have an inner product to create an isomorphism.

Comment: I don't think I'm asking the same thing, here. Forgive me if I am.

Comment: If $V$ is finite dimensional, then $\tau$ is indeed an isomorphism between $V$ and $V^*$. Then you can easily define an inner product on $V^*$ via $\langle \varphi, \psi \rangle := (\tau^{-1}(\varphi),\tau^{-1}(\psi))$. But that's not really interesting, is it?

Comment: Does *natural* mean something to you? There are sophisticated definitions for naturality, but if you are only concerned with linear algebra, then "does not depend on some choice of a basis or something similar" is the main interpretation of "natural".

Comment: OK this is where my confusion came in. I thought that $\tau$ was the inner product that was defined on the dual. First, where does $\tau$ live, if not in the dual space. Also, what makes it natural? Edit: I think I got it.

Comment: $\tau$ is the inner product, where you fix the first coordinate. It is a linear map from $V$ to $V^*$: $\tau \colon V\to V^*$, $\tau(x) \in V^*$, where $\tau(x)(v) = (x,v)$. \\\\\ It is natural since it is induced by the inner product.

Comment: @Babelfish most recent comment: Thanks. That's the connection I was looking for. I just wanted confirmation for what I was thinking. Thank you.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/82312/discussion-between-shocked-and-babelfish).

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown Not Accepted. This question has further relavance.